# A Kinematics Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

> Problem: From the top of a building of height h = 100 m I throw a stone up with velocity 10 m/s. What is
>   the maximum height it reaches, and when does this occur?

First I solved for $h_{max}$, and found that its value is 105.1 m. Then, I solved for the time $t_{max}$ when the stone is at its maximum height in accordance with the initial conditions given. I used the following formula to find $t_{max}$

$h_{max}=-\frac{g}{2}t^2+v_0t+h_0$

where $v_0$ is the initial velocity, and $h_0$ is the initial height. I plugged in the values of all the variables and/or constants and ended up with a quadratic equation in $t$. Then, when I solved for $t$ using the quadratic formula, I got these two values $t_{max}=1s$ or $t_{max}=1.04s$. I know that it takes the stone 1s to reach $h_{max}$, but what about $t_{max}=1.04s$? Does this solution ($t_{max}=1.04s$) indicate something not apparent or should I ignore it?

Note: I've taken the value of $g$ equal to $9.8 m/s^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am wondering how you have found $105.1\,\mathrm m$ without finding the time $t_{\text{max}}$ when the maximum height $h_{\text{max}}$ is reached.

The speed as a function of time is $v(t)=v_0-gt$, so it vanishes for time $t_{\text{max}}=v_0/g$. The height reached at $t_{\text{max}}$ is $h_{\text{max}}=h_0+\int_0^{t_{\text{max}}}v(t)\,\mathrm d t=v_0^2/2g$, which is the result you have found.

Comment: I used this formula: $-2g(h_{max}-h_0)=v^2-v_0^2$, where I put v = 0, because at maximum height, the velocity must have been momentarily zero.

Comment: @SamamaFahim. Thanks for the explanation. So you have used the conservation of mechanical energy and not the dynamics equations. You must have made a mistake in your solution of the quadratic equation, because the equation I get using $h_{\text{max}}-h_0=v_0^2/2g$ is $t^2-2t*(v_0/g)+v_0^2/g^2=0$ and it has only one (double) root equal to $v_0/g$.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can also just use the equation $v = u - gt$ for finding the time where $v = 0$, $u = 10$
and $g = 9.8$.